# How to make space between first item and appbar in listview.separated Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I  have space between items but not between appbar and first item, how i can add space there ?
This is my code

```
body: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: 2,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                    return Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(100, 141, 166, 255),
                          width: 0.5
                          
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                      ),
                      height: 80,
                      child: Text('1234'),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    return Container(
                      height: 80,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(100, 141, 166, 255),
                    );
                  }
              ),
            );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always add Padding from top in ListView.See [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html)

So you can add padding like:

```
body: ListView.separated(
              
              //added Padding from top
              padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:80),
              
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(100, 141, 166, 255),
                      width: 0.5
                      
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                  ),
                  height: 80,
                  child: Text('1234'),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                return Container(
                  height: 80,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(100, 141, 166, 255),
                );
              }
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sizedBox : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html

Example Here :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20, // change value as per your need
                ),
                ListView.separated(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 2,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Color.fromARGB(100, 141, 166, 255), width: 0.5),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        height: 80,
                        child: Text('1234'),
                      );
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 80,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(100, 141, 166, 255),
                      );
                    }),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```